Can data from firebase analytics exported to bigquey be missing?
My firebase project has bigquery integration but there is a problem, the data I see on the firebase console does not match the data I query on bigquey. Specifically, I checked new user data from 2024/06/24 to 2024/07/03, all data matches except 2 days 06/29 and 06/30, the data is completely different. Specifically, on firebase, there are 251 and 266 users, but on bigquery there is only 1 user.
I checked on bigquery and there is no intraday table for 2 days 06/29 and 06/30
[figure 1]
[figure 2]
So can data from firebase analytics exported to bigquey be missing?
